# Print the name of the first letter inputted by user - Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

```
letter = input("Enter a letter to show that particular country: ")
output_names = [name for name in Country if (name[0] in letter)]
print(output_names)
```

I have this and my .txt file is bit long and the error showing is-
"IndexError: string index out of range". 
How can I make it work?

Comment: Wild guess: your text file has a blank line, probably at the very end. Delete it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
Your posted code is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Kevin How can I remove them? (I have 2 blank lines)

Comment: @roganjosh thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of factors to make a small edit to the list comprehension.

1. Empty things are falsey e.g. lists/dictionaries/empty strings

   `bool('')`

   `Out[1]: False`

   `bool('a')`

   `Out[2]: True`
2. The logical operator `and` will short circuit. That means in this case, if it sees something `False` on its first test, it will not attempt the subsequent tests.

Putting it together, we can avoid trying to index the empty string.

```
filtered = [item for item in my_list if item and item[0]]
                                     ^^^^^^^
                                     False for empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
print [name for name in Country if name.lower().startswith(letter.lower())]
```

Comment: I managed to work  that out. Now I have a GUI login and i'm trying to attach it to the main program